# Target container is not a DOM element in react

Tags: reactjs, dom, babeljs

I am new to React. I cant figure out the following error

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Your image can be converted to code text plus the error message. That is better than just showing an image.

Answer (score 2):

JSX doesn't work everywhere as far as I know. You have to create component, so try a

```
import React from 'react'

class App = () => (<p>first react app</p>);
```

and then

```
ReactDOM.render(App, app)
```

Comment: I am using the cdn version of react and react-dom not the node-module

Comment: No problem! Doesn't import it then

Comment: Also make sure that there is a <div class='app'></div> in the index.html file.

Once that is confirmed, use this syntax --> window.onload = function(){
 ReactDOM.render(App, app)
}. This code will ensure that the page is loaded otherwise sometime there is a good chance that react render executes even before the document rendering completes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the babel traspiler to convert your JSX into React code. The easiest way for a beginner to set-up the React environment is to use `create-react-app`.

I'm assuming that you already have node installed. If not a quick Google search will instruct you how to install nodejs.

After that run the following command in the directory where you want to create the project

```
npm install -g create-react-app
create-react-app my-app

cd my-app
npm start
```

Then open your browser and go to `localhost:3000` and you should see your react template.

More information on create-react-app can be found via the following links

[github page](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app)

[react official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-new-app.html)